# Java: why "\uFFFF" converts to [-17, -65, -65] in UTF-8?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Why does `"\uFFFF"` (which is apparently 2 bytes long) convert to [-17,-65,-65] in UTF-8 and not [-1,-1]?

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("\uFFFF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

Is this because UTF-8 uses only 6 bits in every byte for codepoints larger than 127?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

`0xFFFF` has a bit pattern of `11111111 11111111`.  Divide up the bits according to UTF-8 rules and the pattern becomes `1111 111111 111111`.  Now add UTF-8's prefix bits and the pattern becomes `*1110*1111 *10*111111 *10*111111`, which is `0xEF 0xBF 0xBF`, aka `239 191 191`, aka `-17 -65 -65` in twos complement format (which is what Java uses for signed values - Java does not have unsigned data types).

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 uses a different amount of bytes depending on the character being represented. The first byte uses the 7 bit ASCII convention for backwards compatibility. Other characters (like chinese signs) can take up to 4 bytes.

As the linked article in wikipedia states, the character you referenced is in the range of the 3 byte values.